# How to properly draw a table using tabular

Tags: tables

How to draw a table using tabular

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Cs}
\centering
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{C}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
u & i\\
\hline
~58Ko & ~1Mo.\\
\hline
DqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsd. & FDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsdDqsdqsdqsdqsd.
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Using this I get a large table which overflow the frame. How to fix this, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `l`, `r` or `c` column type don't allow text wrap; you need to use `p{<length>}` column types if you want text wrap:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test frame}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{A test table}
\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|}
\hline
u & i \\
\hline
~58Ko & ~1Mo.\\
\hline
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
& 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same table using `booktabs` (in particular, no vertical rules):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test frame}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{A test table}
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}p{5cm}}
\toprule
u & i \\
\midrule
~58Ko & ~1Mo.\\
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
& 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Useful related packages

- To typeset units, use the [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package.
- To typeset tables with improved aspect, you could use the [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package (see the second table of my answer).
- The [`tabularx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) and its `X` column type also might be helpful to specify columns.